# Chrome Extension | How to include library in content and background scripts from cdn

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, cdn

my Chrome extension has two files: content and background scripts. I need to add jQuery to content script from cdn and lodash to background script from cdn too.

In my manifest I tried to add lodash from cdn like this:

```
"background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js", "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"]
  },

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net;     object-src 'self'"
```

But that didn't help.

My content file is injected to the page from the background file:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {file: "mainStyles.css"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            code: 'var config = ' + JSON.stringify(config)
        }, function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js" }, function()     {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content.js" })
            });
        });
    }
});
```

And as you can see I tried to include jQuery from cdn but this way it's not included either.

Maybe someone knows the way how to do this? 
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26):

You can get your scripts from external resources, but it's not the preferred way as stated [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#resourceLoading).

Furthermore, you shouldn't use the `background` tag like this. [Source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)

You're better off downloading and bundling your extension with required libraries and getting it as a [content_script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Example from my `manifest.json` for an extension running on youtube:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
    "matches": ["http://*.youtube.com/*", "https://*.youtube.com/*"],
    "js": ["jquery.js", "content.js"]
}],
```

---

If you must use some external scripts, I found that doing it using a little hack works the best.

The general idea is that it executes a piece of JS code in the scope of current webpage and adds a `<script>` tag with your desired script.

This is a snippet from an extension that required some of our proprietary js to be included:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:
    "document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = 'https://example.com/script.js';"
});
```

And chrome being such a good guy just executes it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but yes, I know this way of downloading necessary libraries and then including them like you did. But I really need to know the way how to include them from external sources

Comment: @Ms. Smith OK, will provide, gimme a minute.

Comment: @Somrlik neither of those methods are working for me. I'm trying to add lodash and use it in a js file added via `script` tag to my `popup.html`. However I keep getting `_ is undefined`. I've tried other packages so it must be with my implementation. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind: I was able to get it working by injecting the package with `chrome.tabs.executeScript` with the file being by downloaded package.

Comment: Refused to load the script 'https://example.com/script.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: yup this doesn't work anymore @Sailist

Comment: I get `"/scripts/libs/lodash.get.min.js"`  this error: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: _ is not defined`